# how can I generate Output 2 to give a fixed delay pulse on a rising and falling edge of Input?

Tags: wire, binary, electrical

how can I generate Output 2 to give a fixed delay pulse (about half a second or less) on a rising AND falling edge of Input?

```
                     ________________________
Input    ___________|                        |___________________
                     ________________________
Output 1 ___________|                        |___________________
                     __                       __
Output 2 ___________|  |_____________________|  |________________`
```

Specification: Input / output: 2.5 - 3.3 V DC at < 40 mA.

I need a board or PCB or something that makes Output 2 possible. this board can be powered by anything, from an wall outlet to a micro usb power supply. does not matter that much.

Comment: "Low voltage like a power wire" 120-240V (AC) isn't really "low voltage" unless you are talking about switchboard equipment.

Comment: Probably best to look for timer relays.  On Delay relay. OFF Delay relay.

Comment: i think its like 4-7 volts ac. ill look into the delay relays and off delay relays now thanks! ill be back.

Comment: thanks mr grammar person... well i looked up OFF Delay Relays i don't think that's what i need. that i think is a constant flow though the relay. i need it to pulse once when it 1st gets power, then again when it looses power.

Comment: probably it will take some combination of several relays to do what you want.  the more details you give in the question the better the answers will be.  specifying voltages and currents for the inputs and outputs would be a good start,

Comment: If you have some standby source of indicator power, an XOR gate with an RC delay on 1 side, works on any input logic change as a 1shot .

Comment: i dont know what "standby source of power", "XOR gate", or "1shot" means if 1 shot mean i would only work once that will not due. i need this to be repeat able

Comment: I was lost after the first large paragraph. Moving on...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interpretation of OP's question.

```
                     ________________________
Input    ___________|                        |___________________
                     ________________________
Output 1 ___________|                        |___________________
                     __                       __
Output 2 ___________|  |_____________________|  |________________
```

*Figure 1. System timing diagram.*

Specification:

- Input / output: 2.5 - 3.3 V DC at < 40 mA.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fzcsy3.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. A possible solution.*

How it works:

- NAND1 to 4 are CMOS Schmitt trigger NAND gates. When *both* inputs are high the output goes low. Three of them are wired with the inputs tied together so these work as inverters.
- On power up NAND3's inputs are pulled high by R1 and R2. When both inputs are high the output, OUT2, goes low.
- NAND4 is a double-inverted version of the input signal. This satisfies the requirement for OUT1.
- NAND1 and NAND2 provide an inverted and a double-inverted version of the input signal. We will use one to detect rising edges on the input and the other for falling.
- When NAND1 output goes low (input going high) the negative going output causes the right-hand side of C1 to go to 0 V by capacitive coupling. This turns off one of the inputs of NAND3 so it's output goes high.
- After a delay set by C1 x R1 (about 0.5 s) R1 charges C1 back up to 3.3 V and OUT2 goes low again. D1 protects NAND4 from overvoltage.
- The circuit around NAND2 works the same way.

Cautions:

1. Your requirement for inputs as low as 2.5 V may be on the edge of the CD4093 working correctly. Also the minimum operating voltage of the [TI CD4093B](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/cd4093b.pdf) is 3 V which is very close to your 3.3 V supply. When run on a 4 V supply anything above 2.2 V is read as a high and below 0.9 V is a low. This means it *should* work for your application. Try it and see.
2. The chip can only source or sink about 0.5 mA at that operating voltage. You will need to buffer the output. You haven't given the information on the source signal or the load so it isn't possible to offer advice on this.

Comment: so in your diagram the top line is powered and the bottom line is unpowered? @Transistor if yes thats EXACTLY what i want!

Comment: What I have shown is a timing diagram with logic levels low (off) and high (on). They're much better than words for this sort of thing. (1) Hit the edit link on my question and copy the relevant contents from there into your question and delete what's irrelevant. (2) Make sure that you specify the voltages correctly and maybe say what they're powering. (3) What is going to power the pulse timers? Is there available power and, if so, at what voltage? e.g., 12 V? If not are you hoping to power it from the 4 - 7 V supply? (4) Check that you've addressed 1, 2 and 3.

Comment: kinda figured out how to remake what you posted...

Comment: OK. That's a lot better. You should un-accept my answer until I or someone else actually solves the problem. I've requested that the question be reopened.